# How do I pip install pandas under the new system?

Tags: windows, pandas, powershell, pip, pypi

I have pip installed many packages using the windows powershell from my python 37 window, but havent for a few months and now I am getting an error instead of an install.

I have tried installing two packages (pandas and numpy) and get the same results for both.

I tried switching pip and pandas, as well as pip and the file name (including extension) and received no favorable results. When I type in the name of the module it returns that there is no module with that name, when I type in the full file name for the module it tells me that numpy-1 does not exist.

As you will see in the next section the problem seems to be that the pypi.org format for pip installing seems to have changed when I wasn't paying attention.

my code (which has worked in the past) looks like this

```
py -3.7 -m pip install numpy-1.16.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

the error looks like this

```
PS C:\Users\Hezekiah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37> py -3.7 -m pip install numpy-1.16.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
C:\Users\Hezekiah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I expect my pip install code to install numpy, instead it tells me that pip is not a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow steps

1.open cmd

2.give full path to the script folder 
  e.g.

> C:\Python37-32\Scripts

3.then try pip commands

> pip install pandas
>
> C:\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install pandas

Comment: I open the cmd from the python 37 directory directly so that eliminates step two. the command "pip install pandas" doesnt work because it is the command window not a virtual environment. thirdly the command should look something like this: py -3.7 -m pip install packagenameincludingextension but different because the pip install system has been updated.

Comment: @HezekiahBodine have you try to execute all above steps?

Comment: like I said before I believe your algorithm only works while working inside of a virtual environment.

Comment: Solved: somehow pip install was uninstalled on my computer. It still returns two errors but I think that has more to do with the current version of pip install then anything else.